# Is it possible to run Stellar over Tor?

Tags: security

As a comparison, it's not currently possible to run an Ethereum node on the Tor network, because Ethereum runs its peer discovery protocol over UDP, and Tor is TCP-only.

Does the same hold true for Stellar? (Either because UDP is always explicitly required, or for some other reason.)

Comment: Can't say for sure about Stellar Core nodes, but clients (applications that connect to the horizon nodes using HTTPS protocol) definitely can access the Network over the Tor tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

It may be feasible - Stellar uses TCP for its peer discovery protocol.